# Getting Error: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException

Tags: rabbitmq, tls1.2, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am new to rabbitMQ. I enabled TLS for rabbitMQ on my local. As a part of it I created the certificate on my WINDOWS machine (followed the LINIUX Step) as discussed in the https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html.

Also updated the rabbitMQ.config file as below:

```
[
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [
                    {cacertfile,"/etc/ca_certificate.pem"},
                    {certfile,"/etc/private_key.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"/etc/server_certificate.pem"},
                    {password,  "MySecretPassword"},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true}
            ]}
   ]}
].
```

Steps followed to create the certificates on WINDOWS MACHINE:

Bash Cmd Prompt:

cd /C/temp/ThirdOne
mkdir testca
cd testca
mkdir certs private
chmod 700 private
echo 01 > serial
touch index.txt

Using OpenSSL CMD

openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -out ca_certificate.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=MyTestCA/ -nodes

openssl x509 -in ca_certificate.pem -out ca_certificate.cer -outform DER

mkdir server

cd server

openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048

openssl req -new -key private_key.pem -out req.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=desktop-s08pnk3/O=server/ -nodes

cd..

openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in ./server/req.pem -out ./server/server_certificate.pem -notext -batch -extensions server_ca_extensions

openssl pkcs12 -export -out ./server/server_certificate.p12 -in ./server/server_certificate.pem -inkey ./server/private_key.pem -passout pass:MySecretPassword

mkdir client

cd client

openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048

openssl req -new -key private_key.pem -out req.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=desktop-s08pnk3/O=client/ -nodes

cd..

openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in ./client/req.pem -out ./client/client_certificate.pem -notext -batch -extensions client_ca_extensions

openssl pkcs12 -export -out ./client/client_certificate.p12 -in ./client/client_certificate.pem -inkey ./client/private_key.pem -passout pass:MySecretPassword

On top of it I installed the certificate of client on Local.

NOTE: My client and server are both are local machine only.

Code that I am using for connecting to rabbit MQ:

```
 private static void RabbitMQWithSSLEnable()
        {
            try
            {
                string rabbitmqHostName = "desktop-s08pnk3";
                string rabbitmqServerName = "desktop-s08pnk3";
                string certificateFilePath = @"C:\temp\ThirdOne\client\client_certificate.pem";
                string certificatePassphrase = "MySecretPassword";
                string rabbitmqUsername = "test";
                string rabbitmqPassword = "test";

                var factory = new ConnectionFactory();

                factory.HostName = rabbitmqHostName;
                factory.UserName = rabbitmqUsername;
                factory.Password = rabbitmqPassword;

                //factory.Uri = new Uri("amqps://test:test@desktop-s08pnk3");

                factory.AuthMechanisms = new IAuthMechanismFactory[] { new ExternalMechanismFactory() };

                // Note: This should NEVER be "localhost"
                factory.Ssl.ServerName = rabbitmqServerName;

                // Path to my .p12 file.
                factory.Ssl.CertPath = certificateFilePath;
                // Passphrase for the certificate file - set through OpenSSL
                factory.Ssl.CertPassphrase = certificatePassphrase;

                factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
                // Make sure TLS 1.2 is supported & enabled by your operating system
                factory.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;

                // This is the default RabbitMQ secure port
                factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
                factory.VirtualHost = "/";
                factory.Ssl.AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable;

                //System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;


                using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                    {
                        // publish some messages...
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.ToString();
                System.Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
        }
```

The above code is throwing error:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..)
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__64_1(String arg1, X509CertificateCollection arg2, SslProtocols arg3, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ArrayPool`1 pool, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at RabbitMQ.Explore.Program.RabbitMQWithSSLEnable() in C:\Users\warke\source\repos\RabbitMQ.Explore\RabbitMQ.Explore\Program.cs:line 71
```

Can anyone please help me to get it resolved?

Thanks.

Below are the things that I tried:

A) Enabled the TLS on internet options.
B) Enabled Ports also.

@Team FYI and Questions:

1. I installed the client certificate on my local - Not sure on it
   as it's not mentioned.
2. Do I need to installed the Server
   Certificate on my local as I am trying to connect to it from local (client and server both are same machine)
3. I need to do Peer verification, so created both client and server certificate.
4. The password added in config and while calling the rabbitMQ on from local is the same which I used to create the certificate for Client and Server.
5. I created a new user for connection i.e. test and given the admin access to it.

Comment: I am assisting here - https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/Xd9vkBXK3ww

Comment: Please check my repo for the working example, here you will able to connect the RabbitMQ with ssl (tls,mtls) https://github.com/shrikantborole/RabbitMQ.Explore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my repo for the working example, here you will able to connect the RabbitMQ with ssl (tls,mtls) [Repo Link](https://github.com/shrikantborole/RabbitMQ.Explore)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).